# Brute force passwords in C (CS50 exercise)

Tags: beginner, c

This script attempts to crack passwords by going through all possible 'words', hashing them, and comparing the hash to the input.

It seems to work, but I don't know if I have written 'good' C. I'm looking for advice on what areas would be most important/beneficial to focus on (e.g. efficiency, design, readability, something else?) in the next thing I write and how to improve within those. I also don't feel that comfortable with low level concepts like memory and pointers and I'm not sure if I'm using them right.

I'm not really sure what I want though so please give me whatever advice you think I need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <crypt.h>

char ALPHABET[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int alphabetSize = 52;

int max_length = 4;

void check(char *guess, char *salt, char *hash)
{
    string hashedGuess = crypt(guess, salt);
    if (!strcmp(hash, hashedGuess))
    {
        printf("%s\n", guess);
        free(guess);
        exit(0);
    }
}

// recursively fill the buffer and check it each time
void brute_force(char *buf, int index, int length, string salt, string hash)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buf + index, "%c", ALPHABET[i]);

        if (index < length)
        {
            brute_force(buf, index + 1, length, salt, hash);
        }
        else
        {
            check(buf, salt, hash);
        }
    }
}

char *crack(string hash, string salt)
{
    // create a buffer big enough to hold the longest possible password
    char *buf = (char *) malloc(max_length + 1);

    // increment guess length starting from 1
    for (int length = 0; length < max_length; length++)
    {
        brute_force(buf, 0, length, salt, hash);
    }
    return "";
}

bool valid_args(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (valid_args(argc, argv))
    {
        string hash = argv[1];

        char salt[3];
        strncpy(salt, hash, 2); // salt is first 2 characters of hash

        string password = crack(hash, salt);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- **`valid_args`** is a well-known anti-idiom:

  ```
      if (condition) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
      return condition;
  ```
- **`crack`** always return an empty string `""`. It is as good as returning nothing.
- **`check`** terminates the program on success. This seriously limits its utility: the business logic doesn't belong to such depth of the call tree. Consider returning a boolean instead.
- I do not endorse recursion when an iterative approach suffices. Try to express a power set generation iteratively (hint: think of base-52 numbers).
- From what we can see, it is impossible to tell whether `crypt` returns a static buffer, or allocates a new one for each call. Consider documenting that.
- I happen to know that `<cs50.h>` defines `string` as an alias to `char *`. I don't think it is a good idea to begin with; in any case you should be consistent: `brute_force` passes `salt` and `hash` as `string`, while `check` receives them as `char *`.

Comment: `salt` and `hash` probably ought to be `const char*` rather than `char*` - and that's something difficult to achieve using that `string` alias.

Answer (score 2):

**Global variables:**

- If those global variables are not changed, make those constant.
- If those are used only in the C file, you can make those static.
- Don't set magic number `52` to alphabetSize, use sizeof when possible.
- Don't mix camel-case (`alphabetSize`) and underscores (`max_length`).

Instead of this:

```
char ALPHABET[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int alphabetSize = 52;
int max_length = 4;
```

You can do it this way:

```
static const char ALPHABET[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static const int ALPHABET_SIZE = sizeof(ALPHABET) - 1;
static const int MAX_LENGTH = 4;
```

**Function parameters:**

- If function is not going to change data behind pointer parameter, use `const` keyword with those parameters.
- Instead of `string`, I propose to use `char *`.

Instead of this:

```
char *crack(string hash, string salt)
```

Use this:

```
static char *crack(const char *hash, const char *salt)
```

**Efficiency:**

I assume that most of the time is spend in the crypt() call. 
If not, then there is one place for (useless) micro-optimization:
Change the following line:

```
sprintf(buf + index, "%c", ALPHABET[i]);
```

to:

```
buf[index] = ALPHABET[i];
buf[index+1] = '\0';
```

Comment: I agree with most of this, except the use of uppercase for things that are not macros.  There's a real benefit to reserving ALL_CAPS names for preprocessor macros (which otherwise look like identifiers, but have different scope and parsing rules).

Comment: Maybe. I have used upper case for static constants and enums, for indicating constness. It is also usefull if you change `#define` constant to `static const` variable or enum value, or backward.